# setTimeout in Winjs

Tags: javascript, settimeout, winjs

Regarding to servers API, i should limit requests to 3 per second.
Here is my code:

```
groups.forEach(function (group) { 
    Api.simpleRequest(uri).then(function (res){
        // processing result 
    }, function(err) {
        // error handling 
        });
});
```

What i tried to do:
1.

```
for (var i=0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    (function (index){
        setTimeout(function() {
            Api.simpleRequest(url).then() //...   
        }, 1000); 
    })(i);
};
```

2. Tried to use **WinJS.Promise.timeout(1000)** as then continue of my promise.

Both options does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just found working solution, but with **setInterval()** instead of **setTimeout()**

```
var i = 0;
var length = groups.length - 1;

var timer = setInterval(function() {
    Api.simpleRequest(uri).then() //...

    if (i == groups.length) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    };
    i++;
});
```